# Why I can't edit the record using ASP and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic

I have a web application using ASP classic and SQL Server 2005.

When I try to edit the record, the web page shows `HTTP 500 - Internal server error`. I try to tracking the error and I think the problem comes from FORM ACTION directory.

here's my form declaration:

```
<form name="frmEdit" method="post" action="/dairypo/master/tpl/queries/qupdate.asp" 
      onsubmit="return CheckOtherInfo();">
```

here is on qupdate.asp:

```
<!-- #include file="../../../include/createconnection.asp" -->
<%
    act = 1
    if trim(request.form("chkAct")) = "" then
        act = 0
    end if
    curid = trim(request.form("hdnId"))
    nprice = cDbl(request.form("txtPrice"))
    nprice_big = cDbl(request.form("txtPrice_Big"))
    nrate = cDbl(request.form("txtRate"))
    csatuan_big = trim(request.form("selOrdSatuan1"))
    csatuan = trim(request.form("selOrdSatuan2"))

    objCommand_1.commandText = " SELECT nkonversi FROM ms_metriks WHERE csatuan1 = '" & csatuan_big & "' AND csatuan2 = '" & csatuan & "' "
    set qMetriks = objCommand_tpl.execute
    nkonversi = 1
    if NOT qMetriks.BOF then
        nkonversi = cDbl(qMetriks("nkonversi"))
    end if
    if nprice_big<>0 AND nprice=0 then
        nprice = nprice_big/nkonversi
    elseif nprice_big=0 AND nprice<>0 then
        nprice_big = nprice*nkonversi
    end if
    objCommand_tpl.commandText = "UPDATE ms_tpl SET " &_
                            "   dlastupdate = '" & date() & "', " &_
                            "   ctipejual = '" & trim(request.form("selBy")) & "'," &_
                            "   ckdgruprelasi = '" & trim(request.form("selgCust")) & "', " &_
                            "   ckdrelasi = '" & trim(request.form("selCust")) & "', " &_
                            "   dtglvalidawal = '" & trim(request.form("txtDate1")) & "', " &_
                            "   dtglvalidakhir = '" & trim(request.form("txtDate2")) & "', " &_
                            "   ckdcurrency = '" & trim(request.form("selCurr")) & "', " &_
                            "   nhargaperiod = " & nprice & ", " &_
                            "   nhargaperiodmax = " & nprice & ", " &_
                            "   nharga1 = " & nprice & ", " &_
                            "   nharga2 = " & nprice_big & ", " &_
                            "   csatuan1 = '" & csatuan & "', " &_
                            "   csatuan2 = '" & csatuan_big & "', " &_
                            "   nrate = " & nrate & ", " &_
                            "   bactive = " & act & ", " &_
                            "   ckdwilayah = '" & trim(request.form("selLok")) & "' " &_
                            " WHERE id = " & curid & " "
    set qUpdateRelasi = objCommand_tpl.Execute

    objCommand_tpl.commandText = "INSERT INTO ms_tplhist "&_
                               "( cUserId, dLastUpdate,ctipejual,cKdUnitKey, cKdGrupRelasi, cKdRelasi, cKdBarang, bIsFluc, cSatPeriod, "&_
                               "  nHargaPeriod,dTglValidAwal, dTglValidAkhir, cKdCurrency,cSatuan1,cSatuan2, nHarga1, nHarga2,nRate, bActive ) "&_  
                               "SELECT cUserId, dLastUpdate,ctipejual,cKdUnitKey, cKdGrupRelasi, cKdRelasi, cKdBarang, bIsFluc, cSatPeriod, "&_
                               "  nHargaPeriod,dTglValidAwal, dTglValidAkhir, cKdCurrency,cSatuan1,cSatuan2, nHarga1, nHarga2,nRate, bActive "&_
                               "FROM ms_tpl "&_
                               " WHERE id = " & curid & " "
    set qBackupData = objCommand_tpl.Execute            
%>

<form name="frmControl" action="/dairypo/homepage.asp?contID=mstpl_idxs" method="post">
<%
    for each form in request.form
        response.write "<input type=""hidden"" name=""" & form & """ value=""" & request.form(form) & """>" & vbcrlf
    next
%>  
</form>
<script>
    document.frmControl.submit()
</script>
```

Comment: what is the error?  what is the code?  how are we supposed to know what is in 'qupdate.asp'?

Comment: when I try to update the record, it get error page from internet explorer "HTTP 500 - Internal server error", and there are the code inside qupdate.asp and add.asp (the form)..

Comment: 'HTTP 500 Internal Server Error' is a generic response; it could be anything.  Turn off "friendly error messages" in your browser, and make sure your web server is configured to output the error message as well.  Your ASP code looks OK after a quick glance; I'm guessing it's something SQL-related

Comment: I've turn off friendly error messages and now it show this error message:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14' 

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'MILKP.dbo.ms_tplhist'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. 

/dairypo/master/tpl/queries/qupdate.asp, line 52

Comment: well, it solved, i just added 'id' on insert query..
thanks @Tom :)

Comment: Awesome!  Now you know how to properly troubleshoot.  Glad I could teach a man to fish :)

Comment: @Tom perhaps your should compose your comments into an answer then blankon91 should accept that as an answer.  BTW blankon91, you should consider researching "SQL Injection Attack" to see how unwise it is to concatenate values arriving from a client into a SQL strings.  Use parameterised queries instead.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones:  good call, on both the answer submission and the additional recommendation

Comment: @AnthonyWJones thank you very much :) I will do your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow up answer to close this out, based on the above comments.

'HTTP 500 Internal Server Error' is a generic response; it could be anything. Turn off "friendly error messages" in your browser, and make sure your web server is configured to output the error message as well. Your ASP code looks OK after a quick glance; I'm guessing it's something SQL-related

Also, +1 to what AnthonyWJones said:

> BTW blankon91, you should consider researching "SQL Injection Attack" to see how unwise it is to concatenate values arriving from a client into a SQL strings. Use parameterised queries instead